# Calculating eigenvectors of a 3x3 symmetric matrix from Cayley–Hamilton theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's say I have a 3x3 real symmetric matrix M and I have its three eigenvalues $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ and that $\alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \alpha_3$.  (Notice all eigenvalues are different).

We can deduce that $(M-\alpha_{1}I)(M-\alpha_{2}I)(M-\alpha_{3}I) = 0$ must be true.

Therefore, the three columns of $S = (M-\alpha_{2}I)(M-\alpha_{3}I)$ must all be eigenvectors of $\alpha_1$.

Notice that S must be symmetric because M and I are symmetric, and the sum and product of two symmetric matrixes is also symmetric.  (Not sure if that's relevant.)

My question is about the columns of S.  How many columns of S will be non-zero vectors?  Zero, one, two or three?  Or will it vary depending on M?  and why?

Comment: $S$ has at-least one non-zero column since $(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)$ is not divisible by the minimal polynomial $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)$ i.e. $S\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

If all columns of $S$ are eigenvectors of $M$ associated with $\alpha_1,$ and $S$ is symmetric, then $S=c\,v_1v_1^T$ with a suitable $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (and $v_1$ is one eigenvector of $M$ associated with $\alpha_1.$) This shows that there are exactly as many columns filled with zeroes in $S$ as there are zeros in $v_1.$

Answer (score 0):

In general,$S$ could have all of its entries non-zero.  Since $\alpha_1$ is an eigenvalue with only one eigenvector (after all, $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ also have associated eigenvectors), all of the columns of $S$ are pairwise linearly dependent and the determinant of $S$ is zero.